# Replace special characters and numbers from columns Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, special-characters

I need to find/replace all special characters and numbers from 2 columns in Notepad++ with a space.  Is there a way to list several special characters and numbers in the "find what" bar?  The following works for text big|fun|dog|cat but it is not working for these characters and numbers.  Example of special characters I'm looking to replace with a blank space: .,()&*'-
Many Thanks

Comment: Can you put an example of what your data looks like and what you want it to be replaced with?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "from 2 columns" is there more text in the document that you don't want to replace in (even if there is a match)?

Comment: In the *Replace* dialog, check *Regular expressions*, and use the Regex cheat sheet: https://www.linguisticsweb.org/doku.php?id=linguisticsweb%3Atutorials%3Abasics%3Aregex%3Aregex-notepad

Comment: “Is there a way to list several special characters and numbers in the "find what" bar?”.  Short answer “Yes”! But for a detailled answer you have to give more informations, for example a piece of data **and** expected result. As is your question can't be answered and it will be certainly closed soon.